# Sign of composition of two different permutations

Tags: permutations

Does the following make sense?

Let $\sigma\in S_n$ and $\pi\in S_m$. Then sgn$(\sigma\circ\pi)=$sgn$(\sigma)$sgn$(\pi)$.

If it's nonsense, is there any wasy to we split sgn$(\sigma\circ\pi)$?

Comment: If $n\ne m$, then the composition is not well-defined.

Comment: If $n=m$, then it is true that $\text{sgn}(\sigma\pi)=\text{sgn}(\sigma)\text{sgn}(\pi)$.